Dockerized crawler as cronjob with database cannot resolve database and run script with correct installed packages
I developed a crawler, but I am struggling dockerizing it with database. The source code is available at: https://github.com/brunolnetto/RF_CNPJ/tree/dockerizer-crawler. It is not easy to have an implementation compendium, but I will try:

The crawler is a script on src/main.py;
The docker services are called crawler and the database crawler-db;
I set the required variables on environment variable .env.template, but you can rename it .env;
The Dockerfile has a statement * * * * * python3 /app/src/main.py >> /app/logs/cron.log 2>&1, which will echo to a local cron file the required cron job settings.

The first issue regard the script run: it should populate the database, but cannot even run the script correctly. Additionally, sqlalchemy cannot resolve the database name to postgres as a docker service.
crawler     | Traceback (most recent call last):
crawler     |   File "/app/src/main.py", line 8, in <module>
crawler     |     from setup.logging import logger
crawler     |   File "/app/src/setup/logging.py", line 5, in <module>
crawler     |     from dotenv import load_dotenv
crawler     | ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dotenv'

You can reproduce the issue with command run docker compose build && docker compose up.
Any help is apprecited. Thanks, guys!

Please [edit] the question to include a [mcve] directly in the question.  Try to focus on a single problem: if the main problem is the ModuleNotFoundError then details like the names of the Compose service probably matter less.

First of all, thanks for being so kind. I ask some comprehension on the task difficulty and my seniority level. My main goal is to run the script on src/main.py periodically. The way I figured out is by the setup on Dockerfile. To run a python script, we need to install python3 and python3-pip. Additionally to that, I need to create the database with owner provided on environment variable and table 'audit', both on file src/queries/create_database.sql. Things seem harder on Linux. :-/
